# Extracting and loading data from zipped dat file into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a bunch of zip files containing `.dat` data files. Is there any tool available in SQL Server that can import data from those `.dat` files to designated SQL Server table?

Comment: SSIS might help you. Depends what the format of the data is

Comment: I already tried SSIS. Those data files are exported in .dat format. Problem is, 
1. data migration tool is showing gibberish result when I tried to export it.
2. I have more or less 50,000 zip file to export. Is there any way to export them all within a single process?

Comment: ".dat format" isn't a definable thing. there's no set format specified for a file with a .dat extension (unlike, say, .csv or .docx). It could be **anything**. You'll have to look more closely at the actual format being used within the files. Once we know that then we can start looking at solutions. SSIS can handle almost anything in theory, as long as it's structured - you can customise it a huge amount. So if you find out the actual format then I'd be surprised if you couldn't use SSIS in some way.